# What is the probability that none of the cans of soup are next to each other?

Tags: probability

On a empty shelf you have to arrange $3$ cans of soup, $4$ cans of beans, and $5$ cans of tomato sauce. What is the probability that none of the cans of soup are next to each other?

I tried working this out but get very stuck because I'm not sure that I'm including all the possible outcomes.

Comment: Zero because I put the like cans together so I can find them.

Comment: Central to this exercise is of course the condition that the cans are distributed with uniform probability on the shelf. This should be said in the question.

Comment: For future Questions please include the details of what you tried "working this out" and point out what prompted your doubts "that I'm including all the possible outcomes".

Answer (score 2):

We have $12$ cans, soup (S) and other (O). An arrangement is a $12$-letter word in the alphabet S, O. We assume all arrangements are equally likely. There are $\binom{12}{3}$ of them.

Now we count the arrangements in which the soup cans are separated, the "favourables. Here we use a little trick. Line up the $9$ O cans, with a generous  space between any two of them. There are $10$ "gaps" (the $8$ real gaps and the $2$ endgaps) that we can slip an S into. There are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ of these these gaps.

Finally, divide. The expression simplifies nicely.

Comment: You are assuming the cans of soup to be indistinguishable, but then shouldn't you assume the cans of beans to be indistinguishable from beans, but distinguishable from tomatoes?

Comment: I am not assuming that the cans of soup are indistinguishable.  In fact I am assuming that all permutations of the cans are equally likely.

Comment: But there are $12!$ ways to arrange 12 cans, on the other hand the word corresponding to two $S$ switching places is the same word.

Comment: If you prefer, we can let the denominator be $\binom{12}{3}3!9$, that is, $12!$, and the numerator to be $\binom{10}{3}3!9!$. The ratio is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I would use inclusion/exclusion.  There are $12!$ ways to arrange the cans.  To have two soup next to each other, group two cans of soup into a pair.  There are six ways to do that, then $11!$ ways to order the cans with the pair together.  We have counted the ways to have all three together twice, however, which is $6 \cdot 10!$.  So the total chance is $\frac {6(11!-10!)}{12!}=\frac 5{11}$ that two are together and $\frac 6{11}$ that no two are together.

Answer (score 1):

You have 9 objets different from soup, put them in a row and consider all the spaces adiacent and in between (the spaces where you could put the soups avoiding to have 2 adjacent soups). There are 10 such spaces therefore:

- For the first soup you have $10$ choices.
- For the second soup you have $9$ choices.
- For the third soup $8$ choices.

You have $10\cdot 9 \cdot 8$ choices to put the soups in non adjacent places.

If on the other hand you allow the soups to be in any positions you just freely choose a position over the 12 possible positions of 12 objects:

- a choice over $12$ positions for the first,
- over $11$ for the second and
- over $10$ for the third.

Total choices: $12\cdot 11 \cdot 10$

So the probability is $\frac{10\cdot 9 \cdot 8}{12\cdot 11 \cdot 10}=\frac 6 {11}$